# Deep Cloning a generic data in Java

Tags: java

I have a generic list like this:

```
List<E> data;
```

and I would like to do a deep copy of a single element of my list, but I cannot use external libraries and I would like to not use Serialization copy.
My question is about is there any way to do that?

Comment: Does `E` have a `clone` method?

Comment: "is there any way to do that?" — not without knowing what `E` is

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Even if E implements Cloneable that does not help since the default Object.clone() performs a shallow copy.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I didn't ask if it implements `Cloneable`, I asked if it has a `clone` method (implying "implemented", maybe that wasn't clear)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca OK, I understand now.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no, i have to implement that method of cloning by myself, for this reason i have to understand if there are other ways to deep copy a single element of that generic list, because i don't like the serialization method due to the fact that the element E has to implements Serializable to be able to do that type of copy and i would like to be able to clone everything

Answer (score 1):

You would need a `Function<E, E>` (or a `UnaryOperator<E>`) which "knows" how to deep-clone the list elements.

```
Function<E, E> deepCloner = /* something */
```

Then:

```
List<E> clonedList = list.stream().map(deepCloner).collect(toList());
```

It is then up to you to provide a suitable implementation of `deepCloner`. There is no general way to do this, since the knowledge of what needs to be "deep-cloned" is specific to the type.

Comment: The OP wants to deep clone a single element from that list, not the entire list.

Comment: @EugenCovaci then... `E cloned = deepCloner.apply(someElementFromList);`.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that i would like to implement the deepCloner method, that's my problem and i was trying to understand if there are other ways to deep clone an element E of that list without using the serialization copy (because i don't like a lot that way of cloning)